# Python: Best practice for large app?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been learning python as I go and getting ready to start a large application to test what I have learned. The application I am developing consists of multiple screens that are accessed via buttons and using **`.lift()`** to move between them. Each screen is its own class. Everything I have seen and been able to learn from over the past few weeks are pretty small applications.  I'd love to hear some best practices or lessons you have learnt developing larger applications with python.

I do have one specific question.

In my case each screen has a class and a **`.____ini___`**. Right now I am laying out all my **`tk`** widgets in the **`____ini____`** sections for each screen.

Is this a good idea or should I be doing this in a different way.

Any other general tips and tricks would be much appreciated.

Comment: take a look into [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/121481/python-for-large-projects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 for big-app programming: test, test, and then test some more -- at all levels -- unit testing of single classes, functions, methods -- integration testing of cooperation among a few units -- end-to-end tests.  Getting fanatical about testing (automated, thus fully repeatable, testing, at all levels) is really crucial.

Rule #2 is to be like an onion -- think "layers".  If all your functionality is at just one layer, your large app is unlikely to be well designed and structured.  There should be lower-level layers doing computation and storage, middling ones applying business rules, higher ones interacting with the user.

In the past I have sometimes applied multi-phase initialization patterns, where `__init__` doesn't do too much and there's a specific, explicitly called "finish initializing" method.  But those architectural patterns are rarely required, if you've fully matched rules #1 and #2 -- the patterns are often work-arounds for peculiar quirks in such packages as your chosen database one, your network/web one, your UI one -- more often than not, you won't need them.